# Change TextView Text every second

Tags: java, android, textview, sleep

I found no Solution for multiple `TextViews`. I want to change the text every second or 1/2 second on `Button` click:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);

    Show = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Show);
    Start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Start);

    Start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Show.setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.BLUE);
            SystemClock.sleep(1000);
            Show.setText("Example Text 1");
            SystemClock.sleep(1000);
            Show.setText("Example Text 2");
            SystemClock.sleep(300);
            Show.setText("Example Text 3");
            SystemClock.sleep(800);
            Show.setText("Example Text 4");
            SystemClock.sleep(5000);
            Show.setText("Example Text 5");
            SystemClock.sleep(1000);
            Show.setText("Example Text 6");
            SystemClock.sleep(2000);
            Show.setText("Example Text 7");
            SystemClock.sleep(100);
       }    
    });
 }
```

But this won't work. If I click on the `Button` nothing happens and later the `TextView` shows *Example Text 7*.

Comment: Awful... why don't you use a `CountDownTimer`?

Comment: Because it shouldn't be a Countdown. It always should be a different Text. E.g. Example Text 1 is "Tree", Example Text 2 is " House" and Example Text 3 is "Clock".

Comment: So, simply put a switch case: if 1, then "Tree", if 2, then "House", ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code counts down from 5 to 1 (displaying that value), then writes "GO!"

```
final TextView txtCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCount);

final int secs = 5;
new CountDownTimer((secs + 1) * 1000, 1000) // Wait 5 secs, tick every 1 sec
{
    @Override
    public final void onTick(final long millisUntilFinished)
    {
        txtCount.setText("" + (int) (millisUntilFinished * .001f));
    }
    @Override
    public final void onFinish()
    {
        txtCount.setText("GO!");
    }
}.start();
```

It assumes you have a TextView called txtCount in your current ContentView layout

Comment: It shouldn't be a Countdown. It always should be a different Text. E.g. Example Text 1 is "Tree", Example Text 2 is " House" and Example Text 3 is "Clock"...